# How to use ajax results in a different part of the html page

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, onload

I'm building a page which presents a list of branches of a store.
The first branch is mandatory so its fields are hard coded in the page.
If there are more branches in the DB for the user than the page will build the necessary rows when it's loading.
So, if this is my current code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function initialize(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajaxCalls.php",
            dataType: "json",
            data: ({'storeId' : storeId}),
            success: function(storeBranches){
            ...
            }
        });
    }
</script>
</head>

<body onload="initialize()">  
<table>
    <tr>Main Branch:</tr>
    <tr>
    <th>Branch Name</th>
    <th>Branch Address</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><input id="firstName" type="textbox" value=""></td>
    <td><input id="firstAddress" type="textbox" value=""></td>
    </tr>
</table> 

<br/>

<table border="1" cellspacing="10">
    <tr>Secondary Branches:</tr>
    ...
```

I have two questions:

1. After getting the branches array with the ajax call how do I pass the name and address of the first element in the array to the fields in the body (`firstName` and `firstAddress`)?
2. How can I dynamically create additional rows according to the number of branches in the array (-1 for the first branch, of course) and populate them with the name and address information?

Comment: My magic ball is in the shop for repairs. What does your Ajax JSON Response Look like?

Comment: An array of branches. Each branch includes a field representing the branch name and and another one representing the branch address. Thought it was clear from the first question.

Comment: No it is NOT clear and still is not clear.

Comment: Well, I guess ewino's magic ball is working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. in order to insert values into "firstName" and "firstAddress" you need to fetch them using javascript. If you're using jQuery like in the above example, a simple `$('#firstName')[0].value = "YourValue";` will do.
2. Creating DOM elements dynamically is also quite easy in jQuery: you need to insert it into another element (in your example - the page's body). It's done like `$(document.body).append('<table><tr><td>Branch Name:</td><td>' + yourBranchName + '</td></tr></table>');` as the HTML is a string, you can insert you own data into it (like into `'<input name="branchName7" value="' + yourSeventhBranchName + '" />'` of course you need to sanitize your strings. More info here: http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/dom-insertion-inside/

Comment: @ewino, thanks. I fail to see where you use the ajax Response - `storeBranches` array and pass values from it to the fields in the body.

Comment: a simple iteration:
    `for (var i = 0; i < storeBranches.length; i++) {
     var b = storeBranches[i]; 
  $(document.body).append('<p>There's also a branch called ' + b['name'] + ' which is located in ' + b['address'] + '.</p>');
 }`
instead of the paragraph you can put something more massive like I put in my answer.

Comment: @ewino, what do you mean by sanitizing the strings? Is it a security issue or just about the look of it?

Comment: both, as users can both enter HTML that can break your design, make it look completely different (and deceive by it other users) and enter `<script>` tags to run code. HTML-encoding the output is just a better practice overall.

Comment: @ewino, I just googled it and saw there's a lot of stuff around this issue. Do you recommend any javascript, jquery or WordPress functions to deal with it?